# Why isn't my Wordpress menu working correctly?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm actually following along with a Lynda.com video about building a Wordpress website from scratch using Underscores.

We're designing the drop-down menu in the style.css.

The default code looked like this and worked fine:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

but, since we needed to change the look, he instructs us to change it to this code, instead:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    background: #4d4d4d;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}
```

Suddenly, the drop-downs are non-responsive.

I *think* I pinpointed the problem to the "display: none;" but taking that out just causes a mess. I tried just adding the background color like this:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #4d4d4d;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

but it ends up looking like this:

[image: Screenshot of Wordpress drop-down menu over the menu links]

Obviously, I want this drop down below the links, not in front. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

EDIT: I appreciate the people who tried answering so far but neither of the answers were correct. Thanks to David, I put my code into jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/DMDesigns/5g9kbf9s/2/

Please let me know if one of you can figure it out, using this! Thank you!

Comment: that bit of code without context like some markup and surrounding CSS says nothing, try adding more info so people can give you help, otherwise it's just guessing

Comment: display: none is used to hide the menu when first loaded. Js is used to show when the correct element is clicked by the looks of it. Your problem is you are not showing the html as well. check out www.jsfiddle.net you can show html and css there and then we can easily mod it and get the result you want. (btw right click and 'view source' to find the html to input). css can often be try and see rather than do this and it works, but its not that hard...eventually :)

Comment: Thanks, @David. That's super helpful. I'll edit my post with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why his code was breaking the site but I did solve the problem I was having. I thought I should post it, just in case anyone else has a similar issues.

I left the code as it was, but added the background color and changed "top" from 1.5em to 3em to have it load correctly.

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 3.0em;
left: -999em;
z-index: 99999;
background: #9adcfd;
```

}

Thanks for everyone who tried!

Answer (score 0):

with `left: -999em;` and `display: none;` contents are disappearing

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #4d4d4d;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: 1.5em;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the left position's value used in the original code:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
background: #4d4d4d;
background: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 1.5em;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;

}
```

and not:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
background: #4d4d4d;
background: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 1.5em;
left: -999em;
z-index: 99999;
}
```